# Eclipse doesn't recognize the android elements

Tags: android, eclipse

I really need your help.
I downloaded Eclipse and downloaded the android SDK, and I'm trying to import an existing android project. The first error I get is that Java.lang.Object is missing, and after I add the JRE System Library, it doesn't recognize any of the android elements (Activity cannot be resolved, Button cannot be resolved, and so on...).

What am I doing wrong??

I tried to add print screen but I can't because I'm new at the site...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, my crystall ball is on repairs... How can I tell you what you are doing wrong, if I don't see anything? Some code, for instance?

Comment: Creat a default project with a single activity and see if there is any wrong...You'd better give out the full information of log

Comment: wait for eclipse to finish loading itself, or completing any jobs, check the lower right bar for status.

Answer (score 0):

try to do `Project -> Clean All`

if that does not work, try checking your Java and Android SDK paths in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project

and Check weather do you any android target Versions

you should have atleast one target level

right click
Prperties -> android -> target version

Comment: Do you have ADT in eclipse

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html download eclipse and sdk with ADT bundle here

Comment: Thanks, I've already downloaded it. Maybe it should be in a specific folder?

Comment: then set the sdk path Windows -> preferences- > android

Comment: Ok, this is the solution for other people, if needed:

Go to Help -> install new software -> paste the link: "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
to the "Work with" field -> Add.

Name: android adt
Location: the same link.

Then check the "Developer Tools" box -> Next. 
Accept the license agreement and Finish.

That should work.